# How do you add a hex value to a js variable

Tags: javascript, variables, hex

I have put #00FF00 into a js variable, but it is an invalid token? Why?
my code looks like this:

```
var color = #00FF00;
document.getElementById("colorDiv").innerHTML = color;
```

Comment: `var color = '#00FF00';` Missing quotes?!

Comment: #00FF00 isn't a hex value - 0x00FF00 is

Answer (score 1):

It should be a string, you may be missing quotes:

```
var color = '#00FF00';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. store the string `"#00FF00"` directly, or
2. store the number `0x00FF00` and:

   - convert it to a hexadecimal string
   - pad the result with leading zeros

```js
// method #1
var colorAsString = "#00FF00";

document.getElementById("colorDiv1").innerHTML = colorAsString;

// method #2
var colorAsNumber = 0x00FF00;
var hexaString = '#' + ('00000' + colorAsNumber.toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);

document.getElementById("colorDiv2").innerHTML = hexaString;
```

```html
<div id="colorDiv1"></div>
<div id="colorDiv2"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

It should be string somthing like that: var color = "#00FF00";

Comment: sorry for that actually it is like var color = ''#00FF00";

Comment: really!!?? I'd never have guessed :p